# Change TFS Template from Scrum To Agile

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem, alm

We need to move from scrum template to agile template, we created a new project with the agile template, is there a way to migrate the product backlog item that we already have from one template to another?

Answer (score 4):

The "easiest" way (and I use quotes for a reason), is to grab a copy of your existing team project WI definitions, grab a copy of the desired definitions (by creating a dummy project and downloading them), using something like BeyondCompare to compare the 2 sets of files, then making the appropriate changes.  Yes, this is a very tedious process, but still better than the alternatives.

You can download/upload the WI type definitions using the command-line tool witadmin.exe.

You would need to add/remove/rename all the different fields between the templates.  And eventually you will morph the Scrum project into an Agile project.

If this sounds painful, it is.  But speaking from experience this is better than the alternative of trying to use something like the TFS Integration Platform to migrate data around.  And don't be intimidated too much, while it is painful it is definitely do-able, and many people have done this before.

Comment: While I am not sure why you would want to downgrade from the Scrum template to an MSF one you can follow http://nakedalm.com/upgrading-your-process-template-from-msf-for-agile-4-to-visual-studio-scrum-2-x/ in reverse